# How to extract content, result of selectedItems()

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtablewidget

The code below produces a little dialog box like the one shown, where the rows of the table can be selected (CTRL key for multiple select, or toggle on/off).  Then clicking the 'Ok' button, the content of the selections are available using selectedItems().  The problem is that each 'item' looks like this: `<PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x00FF0558>`.

After selectedItems(), how is the content extracted?

The documentation at [http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.selectedItems) does not say.

[image: Example of the dialog box, result of the code]

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class A_Dialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(A_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.buttonBox_ok_cancel = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(MainWindow)
        self.buttonBox_ok_cancel.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox_ok_cancel, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), self.button_ok)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox_ok_cancel, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), self.button_cancel)

        content = {
            1: [   'someone@gmail.com',
                   'Some One',
                   '3E0B001E'
                ],
            2: [   'someelse@yahoo.com',
                   'Some Else',
                   '6C8EAA39',
                ],
         }

        # Table for content
        self.myTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Email','Name','ID'])
        self.myTable.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.myTable.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.myTable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(18)                 # Vertical height of rows
        self.myTable.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        # Populate the cells
        for k in content.keys():
            self.myTable.insertRow( k-1 )
            c = 0
            for z in content[k]:
                self.myTable.setItem( k-1, c, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem( z ) )
                c += 1

        # Auto-size
        self.myTable.resizeColumnsToContents()

        # A little padding on the right for each column, some room to breath, pixels.
        padding = 12
        for col in range(len(content[1])):
            current_column_width = self.myTable.columnWidth(col)
            self.myTable.setColumnWidth( col, current_column_width + padding )

        self.myTable.setWordWrap(False)
        self.myTable.setShowGrid(False)
        self.myTable.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.myTable.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.myTable.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_ok_cancel)
        verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.myTable)
        verticalLayout.addLayout(horizontalLayout)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(verticalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def button_ok(self):
        for item in self.myTable.selectedItems():
        #for item in self.myTable.selectedIndexes():
            print "MMM", item
        self.close()

    def button_cancel(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = A_Dialog()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answer mentioned you can use **.text()** method of the *QTableWidgetItem* to get the content.

As is evident pyside documentation doesn't give indication about type of items returned making it harder to figure out which methods to make use of. In such scenarios it is useful to check [Qt class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/classes.html)  documentation itself to get more details about the methods that would be available. For example in your case you can look at Qt docs for [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems) which makes it easier to find which methods to call.

Answer (score 3):

Call the `.text()` method on each QTableWidgetItem. The single argument to the QtGui.QTableWidgetItem constructor is this same value.

More info here: [PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.text()](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.text)

Answer (score 2):

*Hmm.  Had spent much time looking for that answer, started putting the question together, happened across the answer, and decided to post the question anyway and then answer it, for others, then found out I had an 8 hour waiting period before I could, and meanwhile two other fine answers.  Anyway, this was mine:*

**item.text()**

... will show you the content of each cell (for any selected rows):

```
for item in self.myTable.selectedItems():            
    print item.text()
```

...prints:

```
someone@gmail.com
Some One
3E0B001E
```

You can also cherry pick the content of a particular cell, for example, here's one way:

```
self.myTable.selectedItems()[1].text()
```

(Unfortunately the loop above reads downward by successive columns instead of row by row so will have to find a way to deal with that)

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in self.myTable.selectedItems():            
    if item.column() == 0: print (item.text())
```

output:

```
someone@gmail.com
someelse@yahoo.com
```